# Gradient opacity on borders of image

Tags: css, gradient, opacity

I'd like to make gradient opacity from 100% to 0% only on borders of image.

I can for example make gradient opacity on one direction of image like here( bottom has gradient)

```css
  .opacitygradient{
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, 
    left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
    }
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="opacitygradient">
```

But i'd like to have 10px gradient going on each side (all borders), not just one direction like in snippet above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an example image of the outcome you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mask off an image, you can do this.
The trick is to use two linear-gradients for the background of the container of the image, one horizontal and one vertical, that are transparent in the middle and fully white at the edges.
(Note that you will have to use another value than 255,255,255 for the rgbas if the background of the page is not white.)

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background:
    linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0) 5%,
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 95%, rgba(255,255,255,1)),
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0) 5%,
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 95%, rgba(255,255,255,1));
}

.opacitygradient {
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="opacitygradient">
</div>
```

As a bonus, it works in all browsers, not just the ones that understand `mask-image`.

Comment: TY for answer. Its close. Is there a way to make this gradient more "square"? By this i mean to make picture that just like 10px or maybe 20px on each side would have gradient.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't entirely clear. See my edit; is that better?

Comment: Thank you :), @ "background of the page" - background is now white but it will possibly be changed so thanks for head-ups too.